# Matching factory values in Laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel, faker

Good Afternoon,

I'm trying to create a Laravel factory where 2 of the 'columns' have the same values every time its called and the rest of the factory can be random.

For instance, I have the following columns in my DB

```
name
email
phone_number
status_message
status_code
```

I currently have my factory as follows;

```
$factory->define(Brand::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'name' => $faker->unique()->company,
        'email' => $faker->companyEmail,
        'phone_number' => $faker->phoneNumber
    ];
});
```

This part works perfectly, as it should, the problem is that each specific status message comes with an individual status code. Is there a way I could add an array of status messages with a status code and have the factory pick a set at random for that record?

The status code / messages are listed below in array format;

```
[
   '3e2s' => 'tangled web',
   '29d7' => 'get certified',
   '2r5g' => 'art of war',
]
```

I hope this makes sense. any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: if you are picking at random for a record how is that the same as 2 fields having the same value everytime?

Comment: @KamleshPaul - That is just a list of HTTP status codes

Comment: @lagbox the 2 fields need to match i.e if the status code is 3e2s, the status message must be 'tangled web'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as i can understand u need to pick random from this array u mentioned in above

```php
$factory->define(Brand::class, function (Faker $faker) {

    $data = [
        '3e2s' => 'tangled web',
        '29d7' => 'get certified',
        '2r5g' => 'art of war',
    ];

    $statusCode = array_rand($data);
    $statusMessage = $data[$statusCode];
    return [
        'name' => $faker->unique()->company,
        'email' => $faker->companyEmail,
        'phone_number' => $faker->phoneNumber,
        'status_message' => $statusMessage,
        'status_code' => $statusCode,

    ];
});
```